# copying one pointer to other in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a=5;
    int *p,*q;

    *p = a;
    *q = *p;  //line 6

    cout<<*p<<p<<*q<<q;

    return 0;
}
```

This program hangs. It seems the problem is on line 6. Why is that?

Comment: You are not allocating memory for the int. It becomes unpredictable on `*p = a;`.

Comment: `#include <iostream>` = C++. You should refrain from using raw pointers in C++...

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages, and there is no language called "C/C++". Your code is clearly C++.

Comment: @MihaiTodor there are many situations where 'raw' pointers are the right thing todo and many applicatinos where refraining from them is a terrible idea. This person is clearly trying to learn the right way of doing things.

Comment: @suslik I tend to listen to Marshall Cline: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/defn-evil.html If one really wants to understand raw pointers, maybe he / she should just stick to plain C constructs. Otherwise, people looking for good practices in C++ will end up finding tons of bad examples.

Comment: @MihaiTodor I couldn't disagree more. I find people who needlessly use smart pointers everywhere are secretly yearning to program in Java/C# :). This is a feature that is central of the language, and everyone should be comfortable with using it in C++. Amongst many things it forces people to have well defined object ownership and a very obvious object life cycle.

Comment: @suslik OK, well, good luck debugging dangling pointers when exceptions get thrown and all sorts of similar issues. C++ has its advantages over Java / C#, one of them being speed, in the case of proper implementations. People much smarter than me have presented good arguments for avoiding raw pointers in C++, so I think it's a good idea to listen to them, and maybe we'll stop working the graveyard shift, debugging code...

Answer (score 10):

Yes, those are dangling pointers and you're running into undefined behaviour.

You can't dereference a pointer that points to memory you don't own:

```
int* p;
*p; //illegal

int* x = NULL;
*x; //illegal

int* y = new int;
*y; //OK!
```

A correct version would be:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a=5;
    int *p = new int; 
    int *q = new int;

    *p = a;
    *q = *p;  //line 6

    cout<<*p<<p<<*q<<q;

    delete p; 
    delete q;

    return 0;
}
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a=5;
    int *p;
    int *q;

    p = &a;
    q = p;  //line 6

    cout<<*p<<p<<*q<<q;

    return 0;
}
```

An even more correct version:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a=5;
    int p,q;

    p = a;
    q = p;  //line 6

    cout<<p<<p<<q<<q;

    return 0;
}
```

No pointers :)

Comment: p holds the address of a , so does q holds address of a??

Comment: @user1139048 p doesn't hold the address of a. In the address it points to (allocated with the new), it copies the value of a.

Comment: if I do *p = a , doesn't it holds the address of a?? So I am asking by doing *q=*p, what is the address held by q??

Comment: @user1139048 first question, no. It holds the value of `a` in the address `p` points to (which is the address returned by `new`). second - q doesn't change its address, but the its value. `*q` is the value, `q` is the address. If you did `q=&a`, then it would have `a`'s address.

Comment: I corrected what looked to be a copy paste error. You were deleting the address of a (from the stack) in your second correct example.

Answer (score 5):

There's a problem in line 5 too. You have declared pointers but you haven't made them point at anything, that doesn't happen automatically. And dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, as you do, is liable to crash your program.

Something like this would be better.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a=5;
    int b, c;
    int *p,*q;

    p = &b; // make p point at b
    q = &c; // make q point at c
    *p = a;
    *q = *p;  //line 6

    cout<<*p<<p<<*q<<q;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you have assumes there is something stored at p when
there is not.

Is this what you were trying to do?

```
int a=5;
int *p,*q;

p = &a;
q = p;  //line 6

cout<<(*p)<<p<<(*q)<<q;
```

In the code above, at the end of the program, p and q point to the same address - the address of where the integer a is stored

Comment: actually I wanted to know by doing *p=*q, what is the address held by q?

Comment: q can hold any address you want - in the case above q will hold the same address that p does

Comment: but then when I print p and q ,both vary,this means they don't hold same address.

Comment: @AB, you're not copying the data, but making the variables to point at the same address. To copy a pointer, one should allocate memory!

Answer (score 0):

Two pointers can be copied using another variable as follows

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
int *p,*q;
int a = 5;
p = &a;
q = &(*p);
a = 10;
std::cout<<*p<<std::endl;
std::cout<<*q<<std::endl;
}
```

However in this above example the address pointed by both the pointers is not the same.
This will make both the pointers be determined by variable a
In C++ another good way to do this would be using references

```
int a = 5;
int& p = a;
int& q = p;
std::cout<<p<<std::endl;
std::cout<<q<<std::endl;
std::cout<<&p<<std::endl;
std::cout<<&q<<std::endl;
```

Result:
5
5
0xbf9e7498
0xbf9e7498

Comment: You're not copying the data, but making the variables to point at the same address.